# Understanding how inputs are sent to pipes in Bash

Tags: linux, bash

I dont quite understand how pipes work in bash.

I know that it takes an output from one command as the input in another command.

What an output is I can get because it's what the command prints out to the screen.

But how do I know what input a command will take?

Here is an example I thought would work:

```
which gem | rm
```

Unfortunately it didn't.

Which gem prints out `/usr/bin/gem` so that must be the output right?

I thought that was given to rm so it woud be `rm /usr/bin/gem` but I was wrong.

So my question is, how do I know what input a command takes?

Comment: Apart from anything else, `rm /usr/bin/gem` is a *terrible* idea. Leave that `gem` (and the Ruby interpreter it goes with) alone and install your preferred Ruby interpreter (and `gem`) using `rvm`: http://rvm.beginrescueend.com

Answer (score 26, accepted):

"Input" and "command line arguments" are different things.

`rm` removes the files provided as arguments.

A pipe redirects the output of the left-hand command to the input of the right-hand command.  It does not affect the command line arguments of the program on the right.

To do what you're trying to do, try using `xargs` to convert standard input to command-line arguments for executing a program.  That's its job.

`which gem | xargs rm`, for example, will remove the `gem` in your PATH.

Answer (score 14):

`rm` doesn't take input, it takes arguments. These are different. Arguments are the switches and filenames and so forth that you give to a program on the command line to affect its behavior. Input is the data that the program works on. For example, `grep` takes both input and arguments:

```
grep "foo" file.txt
```

There are two arguments there `"foo"` and `file.txt`. The *input* is the *contents* of `file.txt`, not the string `file.txt` itself. Since grep takes input, you can use it with pipes:

```
cat file.txt | grep "foo"
```

produces the same output, since cat is taking `file.txt` as an argument, and producing the *contents* of `file.txt` as output. That output is then piped in to grep, giving the same effect as having grep open the file itself, as in the first example.

If you want to use the output of one program as the *argument* to another, you use backticks:

```
rm `which gem`
```

or this alternative (bash-specific) syntax:

```
rm $(which gem)
```

Edit: or `xargs` as another answerer points out. Many ways to skin a cat with a command line.

Comment: It's worth noting that `cat file.txt | grep "foo"` can be hundreds of times slower than `grep "foo" file.txt`.

Comment: this is the part i dont get. how do i know what is an argument and what is standard input?

Comment: @ajsie: If you type it after the program name and before pressing enter, it's an argument.  If you type it into the program after it starts running, it's standard input.

Comment: Got it! This explained everything. Now I know I can both use the command directly and see if it prompts me (grep) and i could also read the manual (man grep) to see if it uses std input.

Comment: @ajsie: If you don't want to dive into the manpage, there's also `grep --help` for a quick overview of the arguments accepted.

Comment: @Borealid Could you elaborate on your first comment? Why `cat file.txt | grep "foo"` can be hundreds of times slower than `grep "foo" file.txt`?

Comment: @starriet주녕차 `cat | grep` Is running a program, `cat`, that opens the file and reads it. Then `cat` sends its output to a file-like object (a pipe). Another program, `grep`, reads from that file-like object. Cat puts data in, grep pulls data out, and each read has a "context switch" between the two programs. `grep foo myfile.txt` has one program, and it gets to read the file directly and more efficiently. No userspace context switches, and no pipe buffer under/overflows.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the `man` pages of commands you're interested in. These programs will indicate that they read from `stdin` (try `man grep` for a popular command that reads stdin).

Comment: I tried `man grep | grep 'standard input'` and got `If no file arguments are specified, the standard input is used.` as the last match.  I had to give `grep` a little taste of its own medicine. 

Answer (score 2):

These are all dangerous to run if you have a directory in your PATH that contains space or if the command name contains space:

```
rm `which gem`       # Dangerous
rm $(which gem)      # Dangerous
which gem | xargs rm # Dangerous
```

GNU Parallel https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/ does not have that
problem, so this will work even if you have a directory in your PATH that contains space or if the command name contains space:

```
which gem | parallel rm
parallel -a <(which bass) rm
```

Watch the intro video for GNU Parallel:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OpaiGYxkSuQ

Comment: `rm $(whatever)` should give one chills. Always use quotes! I.e. `rm "$(whatever)"`. Unless you mean to delete multiple files, but then `xargs -0` or `find -delete` might be better options (no need to resort to `parallel`).